# элементы с char не отображаются в консоле при использовании linkedList

Tags: c, list, char

1. Пытаюсь добавить `struct of car` в `linked list`.
   Затем, когда все переменные добавляются, и я вызываю метод, чтобы отобразить их -> отображаются только `int` и `long`, а переменные с `char` просто показывают странные символы.

   struct car
           {
               char registration[7];
               char model[30];
               char colour[30];
               int num;
           //  bool reserved;
               long amount;
           };

   struct LinearNode {
       struct car *element;
       struct LinearNode *next;

   };

Далее идет меню, где я просто вызываю метод `addNodes()`

и вот собственно говоря сам метод:

```
void addCar() {

     int i;
    //declare local variables for a car
    char aRegistration[7];
    char aModel[30];
    char aColour[30];
    int aNum;
    //bool aReserved;
    long anAmount;

    struct LinearNode *aNode;
    struct car *aCar;
    struct LinearNode *current, *previous, *last;

    // add SIZE nodes to the list

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

        printf("**************Car %d:**************\n", i + 1);
        printf("Enter regestration number: \n");
        scanf("%s", aRegistration);

        printf("Enter model: \n");
        scanf("%s", aModel);
        printf("Enter colour:\n");
        scanf("%s", aColour);
        printf("Enter number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &aNum);
    //  printf("Enter if car is reserved or not - [yes] or [no]\n");
    //  scanf("%s", aReserved);
        printf("Enter amount: \n");
        scanf("%li", &anAmount);


        // create space for new node and new data element
        aCar = (struct car *)malloc(sizeof(struct car));
        aNode = (struct LinearNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinearNode));


        if (aNode == NULL)
            printf("Error - no space for the new node\n");
        else { // add data part to the node

            aCar->registration[7] = aRegistration;
            aCar->model[30] = aModel[30];
            aCar->colour[30] = aColour[30];
            aCar->num = aNum;
    //      aCar->reserved = aReserved;
            aCar->amount = anAmount;

            aNode->element = aCar; //assign address of element to list
            aNode->next = NULL;

            //add node to front of the list
            if (isEmpty())
                front = aNode;
            else {
                current = previous = front;
                if (previous == current)
                {
                    aNode->next = front;
                    front = aNode;
                }
                else
                    if (current == NULL)
                    {
                        last = aNode;
                        previous->next = last;
                    }

                    else

                    {
                        previous->next = aNode;
                        aNode->next = current;
                    }
            } //end else
        }//end else
    }//end for
}//end addNodes
```

и затем я вызываю метод `viewAllNodes()`

```
void viewAllNodes() {

    int i;
    struct LinearNode *current;
    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no cars in the list\n");
    else {
        current = front;
        while (current != NULL) {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                printf("[%d] Registration: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->registration);
                printf("[%d] Model: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->model);
                printf("[%d] Colour: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->colour);
                printf("[%d] Number of previous owners: %d\n", i + 1, current->element->num);
                // printf("Reserved: %d\n", current->element->reserved);
                printf("[%d] Reserve amount: %li\n", i + 1, current->element->amount);

                current = current->next;
            }//end for
        } //end while
    }//end else
} //end viewAllNodes
```

В итоге в консоле правильно отображаются только `num` и `amount`, потому что это видимо числа и с ними легче работать.

2. Так же работаю с методом, который отобразит только одну машину по ее регистрационному номеру. 
   Вызываю метод в меню следующем орбазом:

   printf("Input car registration:");
                   scanf("%s", reg);
                   viewSpecificNodes(reg);

И Создала следующий метод для данной функции:

```
void viewSpecificNodes(char reg) {

    int i;
    struct LinearNode *current, *previous;
    bool notFound = true;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->element == reg) {

            printf("[%d] Registration: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->registration);
            printf("[%d] Model: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->model);
            printf("[%d] Colour: %s\n", i + 1, current->element->colour);
            printf("[%d] Number of previous owners: %d\n", i + 1, current->element->num);
            // printf("Reserved: %d\n", current->element->reserved);
            printf("[%d] Reserve amount: %li\n", i + 1, current->element->amount);

        }else{

            current = current->next;
    }
    }   
} //end viewSpecificNode
```

Наверное моя логика не подходит для решения этой проблемы, но очень бы оценила помощь в этом вопросе!

Comment: Очень много букафф, но не хватает того, что у Вас отображается вместо нормальных символов? Только не копируйте кучу кракозябр - достаточно будет фрагмента.

Comment: Если я запускаю программу в visual studio, то отображаются длинные линии и иногда какие-то фигурки(похожие на символ крести). Когда запускаю в KodeLite(эта программа установлена на домашнем компьютере), то в ничего вообще на отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том, что вы НЕ копируете строки, которые получаете после ввода

```
aCar->model[30] = aModel[30];
```

Эта строчка копирует лишь один символ, при чём 31-й, тот, который находиться за пределами выделенной памяти, вам нужно копировать все от нулевого и до тех пор пока не встретите символ `'\0'` - в стиле `С` чтобы все строки им оканчивались. Что-то вроде

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 30 && aModel[i] != '\0')
{
    aCar->model[i] = aModel[i];
    ++i;
}
if (i < 30)
    aCar->model[i] = '\0';
```

или можно просто использовать

```
strcpy(aCar->model, aModel);
```

но с этим нужно быть осторожнее - тут нет проверки на запись за пределы строки.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Надо ли мне для этого использовать while loop?

Comment: Отлично, сейчас попробую!

Comment: Да, это работает! Спасибо огромное за помощь!